# Import Sibling Module in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have an Android project recently converted to Gradle from Maven/IntelliJ.  The project has a traditional maven structure with the app and sdk projects being sibling projects referenced through the nexus.  I can import either of the projects into Android Studio correct and build them, but when I try to import the SK as a module into the app project (which is what we did in IntelliJ) Android Studio basically refuses to import it. I'm using Android Studio 0.8.2.  The actual error I get is either

> Specify location of the Gradle or Android Eclipse project

if I select the SDK's .iml file or

> Select modules to import

if I select the build.gradle file or the root directory.

---

I would like to avoid converting to the current Gradle super project mechanism because that would require new source control and would lose valuable history.

---

What I have tried:

- Separate projects, works but doesn't allow SDK debugging and generally is a pain to manage due the multiple windows.
- Using an empty super project.  This gets both projects in the same windows, but Android Studio no longer detects the project's source controls. IntelliJ would correctly identify the sibling source controls in the previous configuration.

Is there any way to get Module Import to work in Android Studio like in IntelliJ?

Comment: I did eventually make the jump to having a parent project.